# Visual Studio Pre-Build Event generates header for solution, but isn't compiled into dependent projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, pre-build-event

I have a Visual Studio 2012 solution that contains 3 projects: A.dll, B.exe, and C.exe. Both EXEs link to the DLL, and the DLL is set as a dependency for both. The build order is A.dll, B.exe, C.exe.

I have a Pre-Build Event set for A.dll: a batch script which reads the build number from a file, increments it, and generates version_info.h, which contains a string version of the build number. All three projects include this header, and use it to print out the version number.

Every time I build, the pre-build event is run, the build number is incremented, and the header is updated. I added the following to the .vcxproj for each project to ensure that it would run, even if no changes were made to source.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DisableFastUpToDateCheck>true</DisableFastUpToDateCheck>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This works correctly for the DLL. However, the EXEs always print an outdated build number. For example, this is the sequence of events in a build. I verified that these events are printed out in this order in the build output.

1. The build number is currently 65 (stored in a file).
2. I clean the solution and rebuild.
3. A.dll Pre-Build Event is run.

   - Build number is incremented to 66 (I echo it to build output screen to be sure)
   - version_info.h is modified
4. A.dll is built
5. B.exe is built
6. C.exe is built

When I run the programs/dll, A.dll prints a build number of 66, but the EXEs both print out 65.

How is the value of 65 being compiled into the exes AFTER the header has already been updated to 66?

Comment: Just a guess but have you tried disabling pre-compiled headers for the exe projects?
I have had cases where changes to headers weren't picked up when they should have been..

Comment: I'm not using pre-compiled headers in any of the projects. Thanks for for insight, though.

Comment: Actually, part of my code base was supplied by a third party, so I do have stdafx.cpp/h in sub-directory. But since the projects settings don't have pre-compiled headers turned on, I'm assuming that Visual Studio will treat them the same as any other file.